# Turn a string into a variable name using window (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, window

After scouring the forums, I've been trying to use *window* to turn a parameter entered as a string into a workable variable. Here we start with the target location in the *p* tag...

```
<p id="rent"></p>
```

Then I call the function using the parameter *"rent"* to obtain the variable *rent*.

```
var rent = 125;
function display(attribute) {
        document.getElementById(attribute).innerHTML = window.attribute;
    }
display("rent");
```

However it still returns "undefined" so I must be making a mistake in syntax. Any solutions?

---

**Update: @Sidd has the right approach in changing it to window[attribute] but I still can't get it to work with object properties, for example if you call rent.amt.**

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it:

```
var rent = 125;
function display(attribute) {
    document.getElementById(attribute).innerHTML = window[attribute];
}
display("rent");
```

`window.attribute` looks for a variable called `attribute` instead.

Comment: did you test that out? Now it's giving me [object HTMLParagraphElement] instead of undefined. How do I get 125?

Comment: Also works on codepen. I think you might be using jsFiddle, which doesn't provide consistent access to the window variable.

Comment: Huh, it wasn't working before but I can now get it going with this simple code. What seems to be causing bugs is using this for an object.

var rent = {
  amt: 125,
};
function display(attribute) {
   document.getElementById(attribute).innerText = window[attribute];
}
display("rent.amt");

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is related to objects because it is working without them.